# C++ AWS S3 interface from lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, lambda

I'm trying to access AWS S3 from a lambda using the S3 C++ interface.

I've created a simple test that writes an object into S3. The test runs fine on a regular VM but fails when running on a lambda.

I have determined that the test runs successfuly until the actually *put* operation:

```
auto put_object_outcome = s3_client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);
```

Once the execution hits this line the process terminates successfully. **Any line after the *PutObject* call is not executed.**

Any ideas what might be going on? Any examples of using the C++ interface on lambdas are also appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have determined that the code is failing on the call to *curl_easy_perform* which indicates this is a problem at the curl level.

My code:

```
Aws::SDKOptions options;

void initialize_aws() {
  Aws::InitAPI(options);
}

Aws::S3::S3Client create_client() {
  Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
  clientConfig.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTPS;
  clientConfig.region = Aws::Region::US_WEST_2;
  Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(clientConfig);
  return s3_client;
}

bool put_object(uint64_t id, Aws::S3::S3Client& s3_client,
                const std::string& bucket_name, const std::string& object) {

  std::string key_name = std::to_string(id);

  Model::PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest;
  putObjectRequest.WithBucket(bucket_name)
      .WithKey(key_name);

  auto ss = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("TAG");
  *ss << object;
  ss->flush();

  putObjectRequest.SetBody(ss);

  // fails here
  auto put_object_outcome = s3_client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);

  if (put_object_outcome.IsSuccess()) {
     return true;
  }
  else {
     std::cout << "PutObject error: " <<
            put_object_outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << " " <<
            put_object_outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
     return false;
  }
  return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  initialize_aws();
  auto client = create_client();

  bool success = put_object(0, client, "bucket_aws_s3_cpp", "1234567");

  shutdown_aws();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your lambda code that is failing. There are lot of things that can go wrong, hard to pinpoint what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Just did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by statically compiling everything correctly (especially libc with  --enable-static-nss configuration).